# Does Vala support self-invoking?

Tags: invoke, anonymous, vala, self-invoking-function

Is there any way that Vala supports Self Invoking? Either with a class, or with a method?

Javascript supports self invoking like below. Which is what im looking for.

```
   (function(){
   // some code…
   })();
```

I'm attempting to load a class into a hashmap for dynamically loading.

Comment: Vala has delegates and closures. You can store an anonymous function in a delegate and invoke that delegate later. You can store a delegate in a hash map. Does that help? What exactly do you mean with `dynamical loading`?

Comment: Dynamic Loading meaning storing it in a hashtable for later then calling it by it's event name. 

I'm essentially looking for a class that automatically adds itself to a hashtable without being called.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Gee;

[CCode (has_target = false)]
delegate void MyDelegate();

int main() {
        var map = new HashMap<string, MyDelegate>();

        map["one"] = () => { stdout.printf("1\n"); };
        map["two"] = () => { stdout.printf("2\n"); };

        MyDelegate d = map["two"];
        d();
        return 0;
}
```

If you need a target in your delegate you have to write a wrapper, see this question:
[Gee HashMap containing methods as values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145635/gee-hashmap-containing-methods-as-values)

As you can see, you don't need self invokation. Self invokation would look something like this:

```
int main() {
        (() => { stdout.printf("Hello world!\n"); })();
        return 0;
}
```

This is not supported by Vala (I tested this with valac-0.22).

Invoking a delegate var works as expected:

```
delegate void MyDelegate();

int main() {
        MyDelegate d = () => { stdout.printf("Hello world!\n"); };
        d();
        return 0;
}
```